Automatic proofs after simp
My previous question about automatic proofs in Isabelle was answered by @BenjaminBisping pointing out how to use simp.
However, here's a simple example which is the result of a simp but which is still not solved by Isabelle's automation via the "apply" button.
Perhaps this shouldn't have a "¬" in front but either way I am not getting an answer. Shouldn't this be within reach?
lemma "¬( real_of_rat (Fract 0 1) *
    real_of_rat (Fract 0 1) +
    (1 - real_of_rat (Fract 0 1)) *
    (1 - real_of_rat (Fract 1 1))
    < real_of_rat (Fract 0 1) *
      real_of_rat (Fract 1 2) +
      (1 - real_of_rat (Fract 0 1)) *
      (1 - real_of_rat (Fract 0 1)) ∧
    (1 - real_of_rat (Fract 0 1)) *
    (1 - real_of_rat (Fract 1 2)) +
    real_of_rat (Fract 1 2) *
    real_of_rat (Fract 1 2)
    < real_of_rat (Fract 0 1) *
      real_of_rat (Fract 1 2) +
      (1 - real_of_rat (Fract 0 1)) *
      (1 - real_of_rat (Fract 0 1)) ∧
    (1 - real_of_rat (Fract 1 2)) *
    (1 - real_of_rat (Fract 1 1))
    < (1 - real_of_rat (Fract 0 1)) *
      (1 - real_of_rat (Fract 0 1)) ∧
    0 ≤ Fract 1 2 ∧
    Fract 1 2 ≤ 1 ∧
    0 ≤ Fract 0 1 ∧
    Fract 0 1 ≤ 1 ∧
    0 ≤ Fract 0 1 ∧
    Fract 0 1 ≤ 1 ∧ 0 ≤ Fract 1 1 ∧ Fract 1 1 ≤ 1)"


The ¬ indeed seems to be wrong. So it's no wonder that Isabelle struggles to find a proof. (Actually, in my case, it even reports on its own that quickcheck determined the statement to be false.)
Anyways, if I drop the ¬, one can quickly prove your list of goals with some sledgehammering.
lemma
  "real_of_rat (Fract 0 1) *
    real_of_rat (Fract 0 1) +
    (1 - real_of_rat (Fract 0 1)) *
    (1 - real_of_rat (Fract 1 1))
    < real_of_rat (Fract 0 1) *
      real_of_rat (Fract 1 2) +
      (1 - real_of_rat (Fract 0 1)) *
      (1 - real_of_rat (Fract 0 1))"
  "(1 - real_of_rat (Fract 0 1)) *
    (1 - real_of_rat (Fract 1 2)) +
    real_of_rat (Fract 1 2) *
    real_of_rat (Fract 1 2)
    < real_of_rat (Fract 0 1) *
      real_of_rat (Fract 1 2) +
      (1 - real_of_rat (Fract 0 1)) *
      (1 - real_of_rat (Fract 0 1))"
  "(1 - real_of_rat (Fract 1 2)) *
    (1 - real_of_rat (Fract 1 1))
    < (1 - real_of_rat (Fract 0 1)) *
      (1 - real_of_rat (Fract 0 1))"
  "0 ≤ Fract 1 2"
  "Fract 1 2 ≤ 1"
  "0 ≤ Fract 0 1"
  "Fract 0 1 ≤ 1"
  "0 ≤ Fract 0 1"
  "Fract 0 1 ≤ 1"
  "0 ≤ Fract 1 1"
  "Fract 1 1 ≤ 1"
  using One_rat_def Zero_rat_def
  apply (auto simp add: zero_le_Fract_iff Fract_le_one_iff)
  by (simp add: One_rat_def zero_less_Fract_iff)

This also gives insights which facts were the ones that simp lacks in the standard configuration for this list of facts.
As in https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/a/4175/4763, I would usually lobby for breaking up the proof with human insight. However, there's an even easier route here.
The original lemma is so clearly false that Isabelle's automatic code generation / term evaluator value already knows this:
value "¬( real_of_rat (Fract 0 1) *
    real_of_rat (Fract 0 1) +
    (1 - real_of_rat (Fract 0 1)) *
    (1 - real_of_rat (Fract 1 1))
    < real_of_rat (Fract 0 1) *
      real_of_rat (Fract 1 2) +
      (1 - real_of_rat (Fract 0 1)) *
      (1 - real_of_rat (Fract 0 1)) ∧
    (1 - real_of_rat (Fract 0 1)) *
    (1 - real_of_rat (Fract 1 2)) +
    real_of_rat (Fract 1 2) *
    real_of_rat (Fract 1 2)
    < real_of_rat (Fract 0 1) *
      real_of_rat (Fract 1 2) +
      (1 - real_of_rat (Fract 0 1)) *
      (1 - real_of_rat (Fract 0 1)) ∧
    (1 - real_of_rat (Fract 1 2)) *
    (1 - real_of_rat (Fract 1 1))
    < (1 - real_of_rat (Fract 0 1)) *
      (1 - real_of_rat (Fract 0 1)) ∧
    0 ≤ Fract 1 2 ∧
    Fract 1 2 ≤ 1 ∧
    0 ≤ Fract 0 1 ∧
    Fract 0 1 ≤ 1 ∧
    0 ≤ Fract 0 1 ∧
    Fract 0 1 ≤ 1 ∧ 0 ≤ Fract 1 1 ∧ Fract 1 1 ≤ 1)"
(* output: *)
"False"
  :: "bool"

In such cases, one can use even simpler proof methods eval (or normalization). So taking the (corrected) positive version, we can write:
lemma "( real_of_rat (Fract 0 1) *
    real_of_rat (Fract 0 1) +
    (1 - real_of_rat (Fract 0 1)) *
    (1 - real_of_rat (Fract 1 1))
    < real_of_rat (Fract 0 1) *
      real_of_rat (Fract 1 2) +
      (1 - real_of_rat (Fract 0 1)) *
      (1 - real_of_rat (Fract 0 1)) ∧
    (1 - real_of_rat (Fract 0 1)) *
    (1 - real_of_rat (Fract 1 2)) +
    real_of_rat (Fract 1 2) *
    real_of_rat (Fract 1 2)
    < real_of_rat (Fract 0 1) *
      real_of_rat (Fract 1 2) +
      (1 - real_of_rat (Fract 0 1)) *
      (1 - real_of_rat (Fract 0 1)) ∧
    (1 - real_of_rat (Fract 1 2)) *
    (1 - real_of_rat (Fract 1 1))
    < (1 - real_of_rat (Fract 0 1)) *
      (1 - real_of_rat (Fract 0 1)) ∧
    0 ≤ Fract 1 2 ∧
    Fract 1 2 ≤ 1 ∧
    0 ≤ Fract 0 1 ∧
    Fract 0 1 ≤ 1 ∧
    0 ≤ Fract 0 1 ∧
    Fract 0 1 ≤ 1 ∧ 0 ≤ Fract 1 1 ∧ Fract 1 1 ≤ 1)"
  by eval

So, indeed, the example is well in reach of Isabelle's automatic tools.
